# Transaction integrity (All or nothing)

Tags: solidity

I have 2 custom tokens (ERC20 + some interface) and a person1 (seller) can send/post transaction that he is welling to sell X amount of token A for X amount for Token B ...
person2 can "accept" that and then a Smart contract will do 2 _transfer to complete the swap.

Everything working as expected, but my question is it guaranteed that if transfer A or B failed both will fail as of complex DB transaction ?!

```
function swap (uint256 sellerTID_, address sellerToken_, uint256 buyerTID_, address buyerToken_) public virtual override returns (bool){

        IExchange sellerToken_ie=IExchange(sellerToken_);
        IExchange buyerToken_ie=IExchange(buyerToken_);

        IExchange.TradeX memory sellerTrade = sellerToken_ie.getTrade(sellerTID_,address(this));
        IExchange.TradeX memory buyerTrade = buyerToken_ie.getTrade(buyerTID_,address(this));
        
        //I need to ensure (100%) that both will succeed or both will fail !?
        sellerToken_ie.trade(sellerTID_,buyerTrade.seller); //will call _transfer
        buyerToken_ie.trade(buyerTID_,sellerTrade.seller); //will call _transfer
       
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `trade()` and `_transfer()` implementation on both remote contracts.

According to the [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard, if token transfer fails, the token contract should throw an uncaught exception (for example using a `require()` condition).

An uncaught exception causes the transaction to revert.

So assuming the `_transfer()` remote function on both contracts throws an exception if the transfer is unsuccessful, and the `trade()` remote function doesn't catch it (using the `try/catch` block) - it effectively results in "all or nothing" scenario.